# How to use promises inside express app?

Tags: node.js, express, parse-platform, promise

I am trying to use a promise inside of app.get function that will run a query which will run on a promise. but problem is the response doesn't wait for the promise and just respondes back.

any idea how the code should so a promise can live inside app.get in express app?

Comment: Could you show us the code you're using? We can't give you a precise answer without it.

Comment: If you’re willing to use something that has not yet benefitted from the attention that Express has, but designed explicitly for promises, you might consider looking into: HTTP Apps with Q-IO https://github.com/kriskowal/q-io, a thin layer on Q-IO called Joey https://github.com/montagejs/joey, or Bogart https://github.com/nrstott/bogart, all of which use Q and are based on CommonJS/JSGI + promises + promise streams.

Comment: thanks guys, it seems the promises does work on vanilla express, but not on the version running on parse.com... so what I did was move the logic out of parse.com cloud code and into a windows azure instance. in the long run I think this will be better for us than relaying on their distro

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    db.getData()
    .then(function (data) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.end(data);
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        res.status(500, {
            error: e
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Would you wrap the connect call too in a promise.. ie., `db.connectAsync({stuff;}).then(function (dbh) { app.get('/test', ...) } );`

Comment: If you have all the app handlers within a database connection promise would that promise return anything?

Answer (score 6):

Here is an answer from the [Express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#use-promises):

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  // do some sync stuff
  queryDb()
  .then(function (data) {
    // handle data
    return makeCsv(data)
  })
  .then(function (csv) {
    // handle csv
  })
  .catch(next)
})

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // handle error
})
```

It is notable mainly for passing `next` through `.catch()` so that a common error handling route can encapsulate error handling logic downstream.